# HtmlDecode - youâ€™ll

Tags: c#, json, encoding, special-characters, decoding

```
public static UserItem DownloadJSONString(string urlJson)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = wc.DownloadString(urlJson);
        UserItem userItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        return userItems;
    }            
}
```

I'm working on Json file to deserialzing C# poco class something like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

i have noticed that its translating from `you’ll` to `youâ€™ll` i'm not sure where does it coming from and I have looked at the json file in the browser and it is rendering as `you’ll` NOT `youâ€™ll`

i tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but does not decode.

PS: i am not sure if this help or not but i'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` for deserializing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not an issue specific to the JSON parser.

More likely, the issue is with how you are acquiring `json`. It appears to be an encoding issue -- perhaps you are reading from a file which is using a Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 encoding, but the reader is treating it as UTF-8. Or vice versa.

`WebClient.DownloadString` uses a supplied `Encoding` to do this conversion. You need to set it explicitly:

```
public static UserItem DownloadJSONString(string urlJson)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var json = wc.DownloadString(urlJson);
        UserItem userItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        return userItems;
    }            
}
```

Comment: what do i need to fix the issue?

Comment: Show how you built `json`. Reading from a file?

Comment: i'm passing the url to read json file... have you seen my code?

Comment: Updated. Hopefully this will work for you. You may need to play around with what you set `wc.Encoding` to, if you don't know for sure the source encoding.

Comment: Great! You should check out Microsoft's Web API Client library to use for querying json services -- it's put together much better than `WebClient`.

Comment: would you point me to blog or site please? for using Web API Client library to use for querying json services